# C programming: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

Tags: c

I get the error

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

when I try to compile my program. I understand it has something to do with the variable not being declared but I checked everything and it seemed to be declared.

```
static char getValue(LOCATION l)
{
    /*return carpark[l.col][l.row]; // Assumes that location is valid. Safe code is   
        below:
    */


    if (isValidLocation(l)) {
        return carpark[l.col][l.row]; <<<<<<<< this line
        }       // returns char if valid (safe)
    else {
        return '.';
    }
```

Which corresponds to this part of the code in the header

```
typedef struct
{
    /* Rectangular grid of characters representing the position of
       all cars in the game.  Each car appears precisely once in
       the carpark */
    char grid[MAXCARPARKSIZE][MAXCARPARKSIZE];
    /* The number of rows used in carpark */
    int nRows;
    /* The number of columns used in carpark */
    int nCols;
    /* The location of the exit */
    LOCATION exit;
} CARPARK;
```

Carpark was declared in the main prog with:

```
CARPARK carpark.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What error do you get? Please paste its exact text in your question.

Answer (score 7):

`carpark` is not an array so you probably want something like:

```
return carpark.grid[l.col][l.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you *exactly* what the problem is. The variable `carpark` is neither an array nor a pointer, so you cannot apply the `[]` operator to it.

`carpark.grid`, however, *is* an array, so you could write

```
return carpark.grid[l.col][l.row];
```